# How to replace one numerical constant with another?

Tags: symbolic

I want to replace the symbol for the constant ∞ with some variable name such as "Inf" or another constant such as 1000.0

The constant infinity appears many times in the file.

Comment: Use the search and replace function of the front end?

Comment: Any other way since the front end takes too long if there are millions of instances.

Comment: People might be horrified, but a saved notebook is just a text file with a lot of structure. If you have a saved copy then you might consider editing that with a good editor and replace all `\[Infinity]` with Inf. You might also want to see after that whether any `Infinity` remain. Use with great caution

Comment: What about changing how `Infinity` evaluates instead of modifying the expression? `Unprotect[Infinity];
Infinity = inf;
Protect[Infinity]`

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily redefine `DirectedInfinity` as `inf &` or as `1000 &` using `Block`:

```
SeedRandom[12345]
expr = RandomChoice[  {2,1,1}->{\[Infinity],1,2}, 10^6];
expr2 = Block[{DirectedInfinity = inf &}, expr]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.159

```
Short[expr2,2]
```

> {inf, inf, 2, inf, inf, inf, 1, 1, 2, inf, inf, inf, 1, 1, 1, 1,<<999968>>, inf, 2, 2, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 1, inf, inf, inf, 2, 2}